# Python KeyError: I can't figure it out (new to python)

Tags: keyerror

I am in a beginners python class and we are creating a grocery list script. My script is giving me a key error at the line:

```
 item_total = int(grocery_history[y].get('number')) * float(grocery_history[y].get('price')).
```

I also think the last couple print statements are wrong as well.

```
grocery_item = {}

grocery_history = grocery_item

x = 0

isStopped = False

while not isStopped:
    item_name = input("Item name:\n")
    quantity = input("Quantity purchased:\n")
    cost = input("Price per item:\n")

    grocery_item['name'] = item_name
    grocery_item['number'] = int(quantity)
    grocery_item['price'] = float(cost)

    grocery_history[x] = grocery_item.copy()
    exit = input("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:\n")
    if exit == 'q':
        isStopped = True
    else:
        x += 1

grand_total = float(0.00)

for y in range(0, len(grocery_history) - 1):
    item_total = int(grocery_history[y].get('number')) * float(grocery_history[y].get('price'))
    grand_total = float(grand_total) + float(item_total)
    print("%d %s @ $%.2f ea $%.2f" %(grocery_history[y]['number'], str(grocery_history[y]['name']), float(grocery_history[y]['price']), float(item_total)))
    item_total = 0


finalmessage = ("Grand Total: ${:,.2f}".format(grand_total))
print(finalmessage)
```

Comment: KeyError means that the key is not found in dictionary, like this `days_of_week["potato"]`. I suggest you first break the long line into individual steps. You will get a more specific location of your error. Then, print the dictionary as well as key before that line - this will make it easier to debug.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are misusing Python dictionaries and lists. The variable `grocery_history` could be a list which stores grocery items (right?), not a dictionary like `grocery_item` which indeed stores key-value pairs, so your code could end like:

```
grocery_item = {}

grocery_history = []

isStopped = False

while not isStopped:
    item_name = input("Item name:\n")
    quantity = input("Quantity purchased:\n")
    cost = input("Price per item:\n")

    grocery_item['name'] = item_name
    grocery_item['number'] = int(quantity)
    grocery_item['price'] = float(cost)

    grocery_history.append(grocery_item.copy())
    exit = input("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:\n")
    if exit == 'q':
        isStopped = True

grand_total = float(0.00)

for y in range(0, len(grocery_history)):
    item_total = int(grocery_history[y].get('number')) * float(grocery_history[y].get('price'))
    grand_total = float(grand_total) + float(item_total)
    print("%d %s @ $%.2f ea $%.2f" % (
    grocery_history[y]['number'], str(grocery_history[y]['name']), float(grocery_history[y]['price']), float(item_total)))
    item_total = 0

finalmessage = ("Grand Total: ${:,.2f}".format(grand_total))
print(finalmessage)
```

Note: the `range` function does not include the second argument, so for the loop to go until the last element of the list `range` should be built `range(0, len(grocery_history))`.